# using mutate to create a new variable

Tags: r

I am working with a data set in R dealing with a variable called `points`. The data set includes every play of a basketball season and the variable `points` is broken down into 0, 1, 2, and 3 points. I have figured out to find the frequency of each team's points off of a shot. Now I need help using `mutate()` to create a new variable called `Totalpoints` that adds up these points while making `point = 2` worth 2 x its frequency, and points= 3 worth 3 times its frequency. This is my code so far:

```
Basketball1 <- Basketball %>%
select("TeamName","points") 

Basketball1 %>%
mutate(totalpoints = (0*(Basketball1$points == "0"))+ 
     (2*(Basketball1$points == "2"))+
     (1*(Basketball1$points == "1"))+
     (3*(Basketball1$points == "3")))
```

I need help creating this new variable that adds up these points while weighing them correctly.

Comment: can you show us the *results* of `head(Basketball1)` or `str(Basketball1)` (by editing your question)? Do you want the total number of points per team?

Comment: guessing: `Basketball1 %>% group_by(TeamName) %>% summarise(Totalpoints=sum(points))`

Answer (score 0):

Creating a reproducible example on what I am assuming your data set looks like or something similar. If your looking to just to get the total points per team Ben Bolker's answer works great.

Also, if your looking to compare the frequency of different types of points incurred by each basketball team or looking to see how much each type of point contributes to the total points, this may help.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

points = c('1', '2', '3', '2', '1')
team_name <- c('rockets','rockets','rockets','rockets', 'rockets')
Basketball1 = as.data.frame(cbind(points, team_name))

# Create Reference column for point types and create a numeric column for multiplication
points_df <- Basketball1 %>% distinct(points) %>% mutate(points_num = as.numeric(points))
Basketball1 %>% group_by(., points, team_name) %>%
  summarize(frequency_count = n()) %>% 
  left_join(points_df) %>% mutate(total_points = frequency_count * points_num) %>%
  select(-points_num) -> Basketball_total_points

# Plot Distribution of total points by Type of point
Basketball_total_points %>% ggplot(aes(team_name, total_points,fill=as.factor(points))) + geom_bar(stat='identity')

# Plot Distribution of frequency by Type of point
Basketball_total_points %>% ggplot(aes(team_name, frequency_count,fill=as.factor(points))) + geom_bar(stat='identity')
```